# Tool to generate graphical DAG from a seed

Tags: transactions, deterministic-wallets, account-control

I'd like to have a tool that generates a graphical DAG display from addresses generated from a seed.

In particular to distinguish which transactions are for "receive" addresses, and which are for "change" addresses.

The motivation is to make it easy to distinguish the origin of coins before spending.

A command line tool to generate eg. `dot` files would do. Any suggestions?